# How to use an attribute of outer class - DART

Tags: flutter, dart, attributes, instantiation

Am coding a Flutter app and run into doubt because not sure how to use an attribut of an outer class by instantiating the outer class.

CLASS A
Hey there !

Am coding a Flutter app and run into doubt because not sure how to use an attribut of an outer class.

CLASS A

```dart
class _App1State extends State<App> {

  late String **txt**;
  late FlutterTts tts;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      ...

  }
  
}
```

CLASS B

```dart
class _App2State extends State<App> {

  late String txt;
  late FlutterTts tts;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      ...

  }
  
}
```

Wonder how to override the txt attribute from the CLASS A.

Thanks in advance !

Tried:

CLASS B

```dart
class _AppState extends State<App> {

  App1 app = new App1();
  late String txt = app.txt;
  late FlutterTts tts;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      ...

  }
  
}
```

Hasn't worked...

Comment: Use state management. Accessing widget states directly and manually changing values across domains like this is terrible practice and is just begging to end up with buggy unmaintainable spaghetti code.

Comment: Are you creating different states for the same stateful component called App? Also, changing class attributes for regular classes is different than changing them for states. Please provide a complete example of the code you are trying to run, with the Stateful widget for each state.

Comment: Try looking at [Flutter: How do I either call a function inside a state class or access a state class attribute?](https://www.appsloveworld.com/flutter/200/155/flutter-how-do-i-either-call-a-function-inside-a-state-class-or-access-a-state-c)